# How to check if a socket is open or closed in PHP

Tags: php, sockets

In PHP 8.x the socket methods return a new resource type called [`Socket`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.socket.php).

The problem is if you have a closed socket, `socket_select` and `socket_read` will return errors like `socket_select(): Argument #1 ($read) contains a closed socket` and `socket_read`: `socket_read(): Argument #1 ($socket) has already been closed`.

I have a service that sometimes can receive a SIGINT signal in the middle of a read process, then the `socket_select` and `socket_read` will fail.

How can I detect a closed socket to avoid making `socket_` method calls with a closed socket resource?

The code is inside this project:

- `socket_select`: https://github.com/eusonlito/GPS-Tracker/blob/master/app/Services/Socket/Server.php#L141
- `socket_read`: https://github.com/eusonlito/GPS-Tracker/blob/master/app/Services/Socket/Client.php#L63

After every deploy a kill signal is send to service from https://github.com/eusonlito/GPS-Tracker/blob/master/app/Services/Socket/Server.php#L53

After the kill, the code send an socket error selecting/reading from a closed socket.

Thanks!

Comment: That's weird, I thought that this error is only present when `socket_close` is explicitly called, `SIGINT` should not also close the socket, and `socket_select` should return immediately when socket was closed on the other end (without an error). Can you show some code?

Comment: Why don't you already know whether your socket is closed or not?

Comment: @Krzysiek I have updated the question with code references. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably add `try/catch(Error)` or use `pcntl_async_signals(false)` to disable signal execution for the time of reading. There is not much you can do when `socket_close` can happen at any time.

Comment: I can suggest that instead calling `socket_close` in the signal handler, you can set variable  and before `socket_select` test if that variable is set. Alternatively call `pcntl_signal_dispatch()` in the convenient place (with async_signals = false). Any blocking operation (e.g. `socket_select`) will be interrupted anyway by signal.